# What does BaseType return for function generic type parameters?

Tags: c#

Given the following snippet:

```
using System;

public void doStuff<T>() where T : class 
{
    Type foo = typeof(T).BaseType;
}
```

What `Type` does `foo` reflect? Does it represent the type given in the type parameter?

For example if I called `doStuff<int>()`, will foo reflect `int`'s `Type`?

Comment: Shouldn't take more than a minute to check.

Comment: If you need to use `typeof` in the method shown, then your method is not generic; therefore, having a generic method like this is not useful or generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata of `BaseType` says

> ```
> // Summary:
>     // Gets the type from which the current System.Type directly inherits.
> //
> // Returns:
>     // The System.Type from which the current System.Type directly inherits, or null
>     // if the current Type represents the System.Object class or an interface.
> //
> ```

So if your class is not inheriting or is only implementing interface(s) then it would return `Object`, otherwise your Parent Class Type.

**Food for thought**: You cannot use int here as int is struct and not a class. and if you change your code to take struct then it would return `System.ValueType`.

Answer (score 1):

.BaseType will return to you the type from which the current type you're evaluating directly inherits from. So if you passed in type B which inherits from type A, typeof(B).BaseType would return A.

As for the example, int is a value type, which is a struct. I believe structs implicitly inherit from ValueType.

As an aside, you would not be able to pass an int into the defined method because of the generic constraint limiting it to only classes, of which int is not along with all other value types.

Some links for more info:

[MSDN BaseType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN ValueType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx)